# org.hibernate.SQLQuery output to an object

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have a table by name Person and it has only one row data. I dont want to take it in list(). Can I get the data of Object type. Below is my code snippet

```
Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
String sql = "SELECT * FROM PERSON";
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
query.addEntity(Person.class);
List<Person> list = query.list();
```

===================================

I want the above code snippet to work as below:

```
Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
String sql = "SELECT * FROM PERSON";
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
query.addEntity(Person.class);
Person p = query;
```

which is throwing error. Please help me out on fixing the issue.

Comment: When need an explanation first give us your exception error

Answer (score 2):

`query` is result of your session select. `query.list()` is your results. and you can get with `query.list().get(0);`

You can cast query list to personList;

```
List<Person> list = query.list();
return list.get(0);
```

You can just **cast** your result to person;

```
Person p = (Person) query.list().get(0);
```

Comment: Hurricane you are just awesome. It worked. Thanks a loads.